# filter youtube links from content with Regex

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I have a input area where people post updates.
So I want to filter youtube links, modify them and append them in the end.

This content is not html, it even does not have `<br>` or `<p>`, it's just pure string.

Here is the code I've got from different part of program.

What this should do is, take all matches, and replace them with html.

```
function aKaFilter( $content ) {
    global $bp;

    $pattern2 = '#^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})(?:.+)?$#x';
    preg_match_all( $pattern2, $content, $youtubes );
    if ( $youtubes ) {
        /* Make sure there's only one instance of each video */
        if ( !$youtubes = array_unique( $youtubes[1] ) )
            return $content;

        //but we need to watch for edits and if something was already wrapped in html link - thus check for space or word boundary prior
        foreach( (array)$youtubes as $youtube ) {
            $pattern = "NEW". $youtube ."PATTERN TO MATCH THIS LINK";
            $content = preg_replace( $pattern, '<span class="video youtube" data-trigger="'.$youtube.'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube.'/0.jpg"><span class="icon-stack"><i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i><i class="icon-youtube-play"></i></span><span>title</span></span>', $content );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

here is a original code:

```
function etivite_bp_activity_hashtags_filter( $content ) {
global $bp;

//what are we doing here? - same at atme mentions
//$pattern = '/[#]([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/';
$pattern = '/(?(?<!color: )(?<!color: )[#]([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)|(^|\s|\b)[#]([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+))/';

preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $hashtags );
if ( $hashtags ) {
    /* Make sure there's only one instance of each tag */
    if ( !$hashtags = array_unique( $hashtags[1] ) )
        return $content;

    //but we need to watch for edits and if something was already wrapped in html link - thus check for space or word boundary prior
    foreach( (array)$hashtags as $hashtag ) {
        $pattern = "/(^|\s|\b)#". $hashtag ."($|\b)/";
        $content = preg_replace( $pattern, ' <a href="' . $bp->root_domain . "/" . $bp->activity->slug . "/". BP_ACTIVITY_HASHTAGS_SLUG ."/" . htmlspecialchars( $hashtag ) . '" rel="nofollow" class="hashtag">#'. htmlspecialchars( $hashtag ) .'</a>', $content );
    }
}

return $content;
}
```

what it does is, it takes textarea, and instead of #hash it replaces with `<a>#hash</a>`
hashtags like you see in social media.

what I want my function to do, is to take youtube links and convert it to `<a>ID</a>` (basically)

It works fine If I have only youtube link, but when it's with string after or before it, it just goes crazy.

I guess it does not work because I didn't came up with second $pattern. which was there in other program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: it's content but not html, pure string

Comment: What this line is doing: `if ( !$youtubes = array_unique( $youtubes[1] ) )`

Comment: I updated my question with an original function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need preg_replace()? str_replace() in your case should suffice.
Also you probably need to iterate over $youtubes[0], not $youtubes.
Plus simplify your code! ;-)

Ergo this should work:

```
function aKaFilter( $content ) {
    global $bp;

    $pattern2 = '#^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})(?:.+)?$#x';
    preg_match_all( $pattern2, $content, $youtubes );

    /* Make sure there's only one instance of each video */
    $youtubes = array_unique( $youtubes[1] );

    if ( $youtubes ) {

        //but we need to watch for edits and if something was already wrapped in html link - thus check for space or word boundary prior
        foreach( $youtubes[0] as $youtube ) {

            $content = str_replace( $youtube, '<span class="video youtube" data-trigger="'.$youtube.'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube.'/0.jpg"><span class="icon-stack"><i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i><i class="icon-youtube-play"></i></span><span>title</span></span>', $content );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for this at all, use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url).

For instance:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($content);
if (in_array($parsed_url['host'], array('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com', 'www.youtube-nocookie.com', 'youtube-nocookie.com'))) {
    ## Now look through $parsed_url['query'] for the video ID
    ## Parsing this out is a separate question :)
}
```

Comment: Actually the question was about the different part, because parser works fine (except that situation which I really think is solvable, I just need to tell expression to continiue until space or something like that)

the question is about foreach part to use `$patter` in `preg_replace`

Comment: OKay I corected my question, it really was terribly written.

Answer (score 1):

The problem when trying to match URLs using regexes withing a text is that you can't know when the URL ends.

URLs can contain 'spaces', `.`, `,` and other characters, so you can't say that the URL ends when a new word begins or when a sentence ends. Besides, the end of your regex `(?:.+)?` will match (almost) *everything*.

If you make the assumption that a yutube URL can not contain white spaces (after a given position/index of the URL), you can change the end of your regex by `(?:[^\s]+)?` (all but white spaces), you can add other characters to the set in order to define the end of your URL, for example if the URL must not contain `,` either, you do `(?:[^\s,]+)?`, and so on.

Then, you set beginning and ending anchors on your regex (`^` and `$`). That may not work when your URL is surrounded by some text, so you can remove those anchors and add the `\b` (word boundary) anchor at the beginning of your regex.

By the way, you can replace `(?:.+)?` by `.*` and `(?:[^\s,]+)?` by `` `[^\s,]* ``

You now have a regex like that : `'#\b(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})[^\s,]*#x'`

NB. I did not analyze all the logic of your regex, so my comments only worth for the beginning and ending of your regex.

Comment: thank you for this, it really should help now, but I went with different answer

Answer (score 0):

try using url :

result in JSON format.
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos?alt=json&q=music&format=1,5,6

result in xml format
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos?q=music&format=1,5,6

Then,
for xml format
use regular expression on --
    
        tag:youtube.com,2008:video:qycqF1CWcXg
and retrieve video ID i.e. "qycqF1CWcXg" in this example

Same steps applicable for JSON format.